# Gradle dependencies - replace one module with another

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, alias, guava

In my project gradle shows dependencies:

```
com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 20.0-rc1
com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
```

Afaik gradle chooses the latest version of dependencies with the same name, that's why v19 is changed to v20.
Is there a way to make gradle use guava instead of guava-jdk5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:module_replacement) on dependency management and module replacement. Try this code:

```
dependencies {
    modules {
        module("com.google.guava:guava-jdk5") {
            replacedBy("com.google.guava:guava")
        }
    }
}
```